# Valums file uploader: get full path to file in file system

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I'm using valums file uploader and I want to display a file path in  textbox after user choosen any file (like with standart file upload). Is there any possible solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Based on my research I've found numerous posts suggesting that browser security features prevent objects from knowing the file system until the appropriate submit action is invoked.

Furthermore they suggest that if you do want to display the full path you'll need a non-browser solution like a java plugin (possibly even a flash object could do it).